# Design bug on the user rank page: permalink displayed on hover

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, reputation-leagues

On the [User Reputation Leagues pages](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/4/alltime/meta/), on hovering over our own entry at the top of the list, we see a permalink which is by default hidden. It also does not need to be displayed.

I think it's a design bug. Would someone review it?

**Default**

[image]

**On Hover**

[image]

Answer (score 6):

That link is there so you can easily find yourself among your peers in the list, without having to choose the right page and/or scroll down. I'm not sure whether it's important enough to show permanently (the current solution has discoverability problems, especially on touch screens where you can't hover), but I guess this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).